# How can I wipe Windows from the command line?

Tags: windows, formatting

I need to erase all my data before giving out my old computer but I don't have the Windows CD.

How can I wipe my C: drive from the command line?

Answer (score 3):

```
format c: /fs:NTFS /p:1
```

The format command used in this way will format the E drive with the NTFS file system and write zeros to every sector of the drive once.

A single pass of zeros to a hard drive will prevent all sofware based file recovery programs from extracting information from the drive. If you'd like to protect yourself from more invasive ways of recovering data, increase the number of passes or, better yet, choose a true data destruction program with more advanced options.

Comment: This won't work when you are booted from the drive you want to erase.

Comment: a very valid point Harry. Can't we create a system start disk and then from there we can do this.

Comment: I know Windows 7 beta had built-in support for creating a bootable CD, but I believe that was dropped for the release version.  Is there something I've missed?

Comment: I am running Window 7 Enterprise, It has option

Comment: You are welcome if the info helped you...I am wondering why -2 for answering this....may be thats how the system works :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/) (Darik's Boot and Nuke).

You can burn a CD from this download, boot to the CD and then erase the disk.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to reformat the partition before installing the new OS; this will by default erase the contents of the partition.

Alternatively, you can boot from a live Linux distribution (like [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/)) and run the [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) tool. It will give you a graphical representation of the drives on your computer and allow you to delete existing partitions and reformat them in a number of different ways, including FAT, FAT32 and NTFS.

You can also try [KillDisk](http://www.killdisk.com/) to permanently erase the contents of the partition/disk.